# Angular: subscribing to http put

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

I've tried:

```
updateHero(hero: Hero): Observable<any> {
    let call = this.http.put(this.heroesUrl, hero, this.httpOptions).pipe(
      tap(_ => this.log(`updated hero id=${hero.id}`)),
      catchError(this.handleError<any>("updateHero"))
    );
    call.subscribe(x=>console.log(x));
    return call;
  }
```

and it logs null.
However if i try post:

```
addHero(hero: Hero): Observable<Hero> {
    let call =  this.http.post<Hero>(this.heroesUrl, hero, this.httpOptions).pipe(
      tap((newHero: Hero) => this.log(`added hero w/ id=${newHero.id}`)),
      catchError(this.handleError<Hero>("addHero"))
    );
    call.subscribe(x=>console.log(x));
    return call;
  }
```

it logs the object.
So if i want to use the object from PUT do i need to make new GET request or am i doing something wrong with the subscribe?
Thx for any advice

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the subscription. Although having a quick subscription inside the function for the sake of `console.log` isn't elegant. It's better to do all the logging inside the `tap` operator. See if the request is processed as expected in the browser's Network tab in debugging tools.

Comment: Ive did it like this just for demonstration purposes, so its "easier" to read. Both of these requests works fine, however if i subscribe to PUT it returns null. I also found out that since im calling it from service i dont really need the PUT subscription because the object is automatically updated in all components using this service. So at this point im more curious if its possible to subscribe to http PUT, or if im not supposed to need it in a first place. Thx for replay :)